# Is it possible to get the a (int -> String) mapping from R.java

Tags: java, android

Is there a way to access get the name of the view-reference as a `String` by means of Reflection or generating it?

Example:

`public static final int main = 0x7f030000;`

I have `0x7f030000`, i want `"main"`;

Comment: `public static final int main = 0x7f030000;` Do you mean getting `main` from the given `0x7f030000`?

Comment: Interesting question, but why would you need to reverse this? In order to get a specific id like `0x7f030000` wouldn't you have to call `R.layout.main` at some point first?

Comment: Agreed with Sam -  why do you need to do this?

Comment: So i can use the string representation for naming-conventions in the asset folder. I'm loading photos, and i'd use the variable-name to choose the selection from the assets folder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Field[] fields = R.layout.class.getDeclaredFields();
for(Field f : fields)
{
    String fieldName = f.getName();
    int fieldValue = (Integer) f.get(new Integer(0));
    // ...
}
```

Comment: This is certainly possible of course, i have to add though that one should avoid using reflection on Android/Dalvik. It's really slow...